# How to change Appstore App URL ?? (from specific region to global )

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

Currently my App is live on app store but in specific region

Here is the example of my current APP URL

```
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/anyValue/id487547243?mt=8
```

But i want to make it global (without region specific ?), and i want to make it like below

```
https://itunes.apple.com/app/anyValue/id310633997?mt=8
```

what i have to do for change App store URL ??
Is there any way to change URL ??

Answer (score 3):

This will set language to Chinese because of **cn**

https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/anyValue/id310633997?mt=8

Thi is set language to United States English because of **us**

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/anyValue/id310633997?mt=8

This will set language according to your region

https://itunes.apple.com/app/anyValue/id310633997?mt=8

**us cn** these are used to regional language.
in is used for India and there are more

That don't represent that your app is only available in that country.

Comment: is there any way to change us,cn  from the URL ?? , my main purpose is want to remove the UN, US,  CN . from the URL

Comment: You can manually remove that, removing that will never Create any issue.

You can thumbs up if got the logic

Comment: I don't know any other of removing, whenever I Goole apple and open their website it automatically redirect me apple.com/in

Comment: Is there a way to force the language to a different language? Sometimes, the default language for a country isn't the one you would expect.